# How to consolidate all my partitions without data loss?

Tags: partitioning, mount

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop.

I have formatted my 1TB SSD into 3 partitions:

- 16GB swap
- 150GB mounted at '/'
- 150GB mounted at '/home'
- 666GB mounted at '/scratch'

Now I want to have the entire SSD mounted at '/'.

I.e., All ubuntu on a single partition.

How do you do it **WITHOUT DATA LOSS**?

Also, I don't want to lose my packages installed through 'apt install'

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Number one, before anything else, is ensure you have good backups, and test them to make sure they work. Then you can be confident of no data loss, however you merge your partitions.

Comment: I don't think you can.  If you want to try, you can move all your files to one partition (i.e., the largest one, perhaps), and then expand this one into the others.  That would be possible, in theory, though a complete backup would be highly recommended.

Comment: You haven't mentioned how full each of those partitions are. If they're very full that makes things a lot more difficult. If they're mostly empty, it's much easier. How full is each partition?

Comment: You have to do three things to make sure there is no data loss. First you have to make a backup in an external media. Second, you have to make a second backup using another external media using a different method. Third , make another backup in another external media using a third method. Finally, test the backup by restoring into a different media to make sure there are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

To do that without data loss, make sure you have a good backup of your data.

No, you cannot (practically) repartition your drive without removing data from the partitions that you want to eliminate. While it is theoretically possible to 1) move data to the partition you want to keep 2) move and shrink the partition you want to delete, 3) enlarge the partition you want to keep and 4) start back at 1) to move more data, that will take a very long time with quite some chance it goes wrong at some point (especially the move of partitions).

Thus instead, you want to 1) ensure your backups are up to date and good, 2) erase the partitions you do not anymore want 3) enlarge the root partition 4) restore all data from your backup. Copying the data back is the only step that takes more time, depending on the amount of data and the speed of the backup medium.

Even without your wish to repartition, you should have a good backup of your data in the first place. If you do not, or don't care to, then your data do not matter to you. You may then comfortably delete your data while repartitioning. Otherwise, you will lose your data soon enough at some time in the future, anyway.